# 2011 ESRI DevSummit

Tags: esri-company, development

This is probably more of a community wiki question.

Who will be attending the ESRI Developer Summit next month in Palm Springs?

Which sessions and/or new products look most interesting to you?

What tips would you give for attendees who are there for the first time?

Thanks.

And for the UK there is http://www.esriuk.com/trainingevents/events/dev_conference11/ [Birmingham, UK] for those cannot attend the US ESRI Summit.

Comment: And how will you be promoting gis.stackexchange.com? ;)

Comment: What are thoughts on having a gis.se get-together, perhaps over tasty beverages?

Comment: Stackexchange is kindly sponsoring my attendance.  An Esri rep has asked me to provide some info. The info might be presented during the plenary when they talk about resources available to developers.    **What would the community like for Esri to say about stackexchange during the plenary?**

Comment: @Kirk, I would definitely want you to emphasize that stackexchange is open to users at all experience levels, and how it is a great to learn more about the problems other users face.

Comment: @Chad yeah, but I think we need a theme ... how about "the only good bug is a dead bug" and show how gis.se can help fix bugs.  Maybe SE could cater it with insect fare.  Check out the video [here](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052748703293204576106072340020728.html).  This would also appeal to attendees wanting enviro friendly cuisine.

Comment: @Kirk - Actually what I was talking about was those of that are active here on gis.se getting together to meet one another. Your idea is a little more adventurous - plus I'll leave the bug eating to my boys...

Comment: @Chad now that I've eaten lunch, beer does sound better than bugs.  Any suggestions for a location?

Comment: Tuesday from 6pm-8pm is "Meet the Teams". This year, it's by the pool!

Comment: All, I have some ideas for Palm Springs meetup locations (just by looking on Yelp). Should I start a question in main or meta, add my locations as answers so people can vote and also add their ideas for meetup locations?

Comment: Wanted to let everyone know that gis.se got a mention and a slide with a screenshot of the new design in today's Plenary talk at the ESRI Developer Summit in Palm Springs. They were talking about developer resources at the time, and I think attendance is about 3,400 this year, so a nice chunk of folks got learned about the site. Nice job! I tried to get a pic, but missed the opportunity. Anyone get a shot of it?

Comment: Chad:  Here is the slide about gis.se that was used during the Plenary.  http://downloads2.esri.com/resources/mediagallery/gis_se.jpg

Comment: Also, the video that covered the promotion of gis.se is here:  http://www.esri.com/events/devsummit/videos-and-photos/index.html , click on the "Plenary - Part 2" video and scroll ahead to about 8:45 minutes in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember that technical sessions are videotaped and posted after the conference if you're having trouble deciding between two. If a presentation will be repeated, it will be on  Thursday afternoon.

If you attend a technical session, please fill out the evaluation form. Yes, the presenters do get to see the comments (after they've been transcribed) and comments about general issues were passed on to presenters this year.

If you're looking for a particular Esri employee, you can ask in the Showcase for someone to check their schedule--to see when they're giving a presentation or have 'island' duty.

When asking about an issue at one of the product islands, you may well get, "Unfortunately, that's not my area; let me see who's available." The people on the islands (like me!) are often not generalists.

As others have commented, don't be afraid to step up and talk to the Esri employees. At the product islands, we get told to not group together as it's harder for customers to 'break in'. Although some groups are valid as several people are listening to a customer, other times we're just chatting--waiting for someone to talk to us!

Technical Support and Customer Service are available in the Showcase.

The Showcase closes Wednesday at 6 PM.

Std Disclaimer: I work for Esri as a product engineer on the 'projection engine'.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going, went last year for the first time. It's a great dork-fest! Here's my 2 cents:

1. I didn't attend hardly any of the demo theaters last year, so I'm planning on hitting those more this year
2. The EXPO is only open on Monday, so if you want to check out the vendors, you gotta do it on Monday
3. Don't be shy - if you are walking through the ESRI showcase and you see a ESRI staff member that gave a talk of interest to you and/or you have questions, grab them and talk to them, that's what they are there for.
4. DO NOT miss the party on Thursday night, last year was a blast
5. If you like burgers, you MUST go to [Tylers](http://www.yelp.com/biz/tylers-burgers-palm-springs) - only open for lunch and cash only

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Stackexchange for sponsoring me to attend the Dev Summit!  It was great to meet so many people who have been active here at gis.stackexchange. A couple of the videos from day 1 of the Dev Summit have been posted [here](http://www.esri.com/events/devsummit/videos-and-photos/index.html). Over the next couple weeks more videos should get posted.

Here are some of the Dev Summit highlights for me:

**ArcGIS Application Builder For Microsoft Silverlight**

If you [sign up for beta program](http://betacommunity.esri.com/) you can download it.  Installation on Win7 64bit was a bit tricky for me, but now is working.  It is extensible via [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/), so even though the app you build is called a *Viewer*, it can be extended to support editing.

**Side by Side (SxS) Runtime deployment for 10.1**

[GIS on a stick](http://www.spatiallyadjusted.com/2007/09/27/portable-gis-gis-on-a-usb-stick/) with Esri will be supported on 10.1.  I wonder if I can have two development versions on the same machine.  Read more on [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7242/arcgis-10-1-lightweight-runtime).

**Sessions**

I attended some excellent user tracks and tech sessions, including:

- [Enterprise GIS Using a Framework
  Approach - Silverlight](http://events.esri.com/bpc/2011/dev_agenda/index.cfm?fa=Session_Detail_Form&SessionId=186&ScheduleId=304)
- [Enterprise PDF Export Solution with
  a Single SOE](http://events.esri.com/bpc/2011/dev_agenda/index.cfm?fa=Session_Detail_Form&SessionId=189&ScheduleId=310)
- [Using Python to Glue it all
  Together](http://events.esri.com/bpc/2011/dev_agenda/index.cfm?fa=Session_Detail_Form&SessionId=52&ScheduleId=139)
- [Advanced Development with ArcGIS API
  for Microsoft Silverlight/WPF](http://events.esri.com/bpc/2011/dev_agenda/index.cfm?fa=Session_Detail_Form&SessionId=71&ScheduleId=159)
- [Advanced Development with ArcGIS API
  for Windows Phone](http://events.esri.com/bpc/2011/dev_agenda/index.cfm?fa=Session_Detail_Form&SessionId=47&ScheduleId=166)

I'll update this with links to actual presentations when they are posted later.

**GIS Data in the Cloud**

I hadn't been following Azure, so it was news to me that spatial types are supported.  Now if only microsoft could figure out a way to host a [geometric network in Azure](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/can-a-geometric-network-be-hosted-in-a-spatial-data-service).  Until then I'll need to use Amazon web services ... they said they might even [host my geometric network for free](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6611/what-gis-data-should-amazon-add-to-its-public-data-sets).  I heard rumors that Entity Framework will soon support spatial types.   Esri continues to devote a lot of resources to [ArcGIS Online](http://www.arcgis.com/home/).  I didn't hear any discussion of the ArcGIS OnLine business model though.

**Dodgeball (Next Olympic Sport?)**

Couldn't get enough people together in time for a GIS.StackExchange team, but had a blast watching.  Now if only I could remember those 5 D's ...

**Update**

Video of a [Road Map for ArcGIS Server Developers](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/video/arcgis-server/details?entryID=C0806E5E-1422-2418-A02E-CF00BF8ABEC7) has been published.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Chad, definately don't be shy as you won't get anything from it.

I'm always interested in what is coming out on the radar, it does give you a good heads up.  It's also great to get to meet Esri Inc. developers especially if you're not in the US and have some questions your dying to get answered.

I wasn't impressed with the UK one - very limited as it's only just started up.  If you're a desktop developer only then you won't get much from the UK one.  In comparison terms if you're going to go to a dev summit and you are a serious ESRI GIS developer then there is nothing that currently replaces the dev summit.  If you can't get to the US then unless there is someting specific you want to see on the UK agende then I suggest spending a day looking into researching something new, much more worth it.  Unless you have a dying need to get out of the office for a day ;)

Don't forget you can get the videoed sessions from the devsummit on the dev summit page after a couple of weeks or month.  They don't replace going but they can be really useful.

Comment: [Here's](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit10/index.html) video from last year.

Answer (score 2):

**gis.se user meetup**

It has been suggested to have a meetup of sorts of gis.se users on Tuesday night after the Meet the Teams event (which Melita informed is by the pool this year) - a chance to get to know one another. Kirk and myself are definitely in, anyone else who's interested leave a comment on this answer, please. Also, if you have ideas for a venue (hotel bar is fine by me), leave that as well.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with all the answers so far.   If you cannot attend, try to watch the [#devsummit](http://twitter.com/#!/search/devsummit) hashtag on twitter to get a pulse on what everyone there is saying.  Also watch for the Plenary videos which will be uploaded onto the DevSummit site later in the evening of March 8th.  http://www.esri.com/devsummit   We will also start loading all 130 or so tech session videos onto the ArcGIS Resource Center starting the end of next week (3/12 or so).  http://resources.arcgis.com/

Answer (score 2):

Make it a point to attend at least one user presentation or watch the videos once they have been posted. They are generally very well done and provide a good opportunity to see what other developers are working on. Plus, they are a nice diversion from the standard ESRI tech session format.