# What GIS Data should Amazon add to its Public Data Sets?

Tags: data, cloud-gis, amazon-ec2

Amazon [says](http://aws.amazon.com/publicdatasets/#3):

> If you have a public domain or
>   non-proprietary data set that you
>   think is useful and interesting to the
>   AWS community, please submit a request
>   below and the AWS team will review
>   your submission and get back to you.
>   Typically the data sets in the
>   repository are between 1 GB to 1 TB in
>   size (based on the Amazon EBS volume
>   limit), but we can work with you to
>   host larger data sets as well. You
>   must have the right to make the data
>   freely available.

Given that Amazon is a [gold sponsor](http://www.esri.com/events/devsummit/exhibits/index.html) at the Esri Dev Summit, maybe this would be a good time for the community to recommend data sets for Amazon to put in their cloud.

Having the data on Amazon allows fast access by things like Server Object Extensions and geoprocessing services running on EC2.

Currently I just see [3 datasets for geography](http://aws.amazon.com/datasets/Geographic?browse=1).

**Update**
I dropped by Amazon's booth at the Dev Summit and spoke a bit with an AWS rep.  He said they are still sorting out how they will keep public dataset current.  He said there has been a lot of interest from the Human Genome community.  He said to expect something in last half of 2011 regarding changes to community data sets that will make it easier for GIS.

I also visited with Microsoft.  While Azure looks promising, it doesn't look like you'd be able to do server-side [geometric network traversal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/can-a-geometric-network-be-hosted-in-a-spatial-data-service), as you would with AWS.

Comment: The shapefiles are in a linux volume, so can't be attached to a windows instance. http://aws.amazon.com/datasets/Geographic/2367

Answer (score 5):

It's one thing to add data, it's another to keep it current. I note that the Open Street Map data listed on AWS hasn't been updated since Oct 2009.

I'd like all the Canadian public data from [Geobase.ca](http://geobase.ca/) and [GeoGratis](http://geogratis.cgdi.gc.ca/geogratis/en/index.html) to be available on some well performing public access service, be it AWS or ArcGIS Online or ..., but only if it's going to keep pace with upstream releases. I'm sure the same opinion will be held by many others for their respective homelands.

Comment: Good point about keeping data current.  I'd like to see the Alberta Township System (ATS) polygons put in the cloud. It doesn't seem like it would change very often. I guess there are licensing issues though. http://www.altalis.com/prod_prop_ats.html

Comment: Speaking of Canadian data, it's a shame that we have geobase, geogratis, and enviro can data all for free, but we have to pay ridiculous amounts to get census data

Comment: I just noticed this thread where AWS suggests how to keep OSM up to date.  Not sure how practical that would be.  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=144220#144220

Answer (score 4):

The smallest possible census block data for most of the world and not just US, also be able to access some of the data and do analysis on it

Answer (score 4):

A global highest resolution Landsat mosaic.

SRTM

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to see the [National Hydrography Dataset](http://services.nationalmap.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/nhd/MapServer) (NHD) added.

Assuming the data would be made available as geometric networks in file geodatabases (similar to what can be downloaded), I'd be able to provide an SOE that performs network traces.  I realize this is a large dataset, but feel it would benefit a lot of environmental efforts.  Besides, with a name like "Amazon" there really needs to be good hydro data.

Answer (score 2):

I think a good, basic addition would be Nat'l, State, County, and Town borders.

Wouldn't expect it to require updates as often as some of the other suggestions, and it's most often an essential component of many analyses.

Answer (score 1):

Worldwide hillshade of many resolutions (medium / large scale)