# Can a Geometric network be hosted in a Spatial Data Service?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, geometric-network

I'm wanting to deploy a [geometric network](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/4ade6abc-df6e-4e5b-b68b-9f372cd3e18d.htm) to [Sql Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlazure/database.aspx), where clients can trace through it.

The [Spatial Data Services Deployment Utility](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/mapit/archive/2009/12/18/Spatial-Data-Service-Deployment-Utility-for-Windows-Azure-is-available_2100_.aspx) allows me to deploy each featureclass from a geometric network into its own [Azure Spatial Data Service](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/MapIt/v1.1/help/index.htm?page=how_do_i_serve_my_data_qst_.htm).  However, I don't see a way to perform traces.  Since [Sql Server Spatial Tools](http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/) still [can't be deployed to Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394115.aspx) I would not even be able to roll my own tracing.

Is there a way to host a Geometric network in Sql Azure with tracing functionality exposed?

Answer (score 1):

I heard back from an Esri rep that this is not currently supported, but hinted that it might be in the future.

I guess this means that until then, if I want to put a geometric network into the cloud, I'll need to use Amazon EC2.  Another Esri rep I spoke with at the Dev Summit said there won't be any OOTB tracing in 10.1, and recommended that I write an SOE that exposes tracing capabilities implemented with arcobjects.  It appears that ArcFM [supports this](http://resources.arcfmsolution.com/ServerSDK/webframe.html?ElectricTraceREST10.html) at 10.0.1.

Comment: Kirk, you can also see my soe http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/ArcObjects-.NET-API-Code-Gallery/details?entryID=0F09D031-1422-2418-8839-02AE02C23A15