# ArcGIS 10.1 Lightweight Runtime

Tags: arcgis-10.1

Does anyone know where I can find more information about the new Lightweight Runtime that will be included with ArcGIS 10.1?  This was discussed at the recent DevSummit and ESRI Federal User Conference.

I am looking for any general information about the product, but more specifically I am trying to find out if there will be any sort of licensing fees to use it.

More information can be found here:
http://esriaustralia.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/the-new-arcgis-runtime/

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the DevSummit 2011 a long session was presented by Euan Cameron. As far as I understood from the session Geodatabases will be supported. There will be a license fee. It will be less that ArcEngine but it will more than the old price of MapObjects. As James mentioned keep an eye on the beta community website. BTW: if you have a EDN license you will be able to develop for ArcGIS Runtime.

Answer (score 8):

Esri Australia [blogged about it](http://esriaustralia.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/the-new-arcgis-runtime/).  I think runtime is definitely a step in the right direction.  Since Esri is looking into new ways to bundle assemblies, I'd really like them to **consider supporting Geodatabase Add-ins**.  This would allow assemblies to be deployed via the geodatabase.  I've submitted this to [Ideas.Esri.Com](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008L04).

**Update**: [Video for Plenary 2](http://www.esri.com/events/devsummit/videos-and-photos/index.html) beginning at 67:20 discusses Runtime.

Comment: Yeah, that could be very helpful if they include edit capabilities they give for the runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Information on the new runtime is pretty limited at this point since it hasn't been released yet. You may want to get on the [beta website for Esri](https://betacommunity.esri.com/home.html), though a public beta is not available yet (as of Marc 14, 2011). Once the beta is out, there will be forums available to ask questions about the product.

I didn't get the names of the presenters for that session at Dev Summit, but you can contact the presenters directly for more information if you have their names.

Answer (score 1):

Euan Cameron, Mary Harvey, and Ralf Gottschalk's presentation is up on the video.esri.com site now.

http://video.esri.com/watch/679/road-ahead-arcgis-runtime